# PL/I-type PUT DATA method for Java

Tags: java

In PL/I there's a nice statement called "PUT DATA" which is used like so:

```
NAME := 'ROBBY' 
AGE = 30
PUT DATA ( NAME, AGE )
```

The output from that statement would be:

**NAME = ROBBY,  AGE = 30**

To do so in Java would require a lot of care with quotes, spaces, and plus signs:

```
System.out.println ( "Name = " + name + ", age = " + age ) ;
```

I'm far too new at Java to have a feel for how impossible making a "putData" method would be. I should think about it first, I guess, but I mainly wondered if maybe it already exists, even in a one-argument-only form.

```
putData (name);
```

would very cleanly produce

**name = ROBBY**

vs.

```
System.out.println( "name = " + name )
```

which is nerve-wracking even with just one "equation" to display.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
System.out.printf("${EXP instanceof="<any>" default="exp"} = %s\n" , ${EXP});
```

The Netbeans template above does what Idan's suggestion (in Answer below)

```
System.out.printf("name = %s\n",name);
```

does and does NOT require typing `name` twice, besides having the advantage of enabling the following output:

```
x+y+z = 12
```

merely by typing `x+y+z` in the "args box", which results in this code:

```
System.out.printf("\nx+y+z = %s\n", x+y+z);
```

where the following initializations are given: x = 3 , y = 4, and z = 5.

Answer (score 0):

What you want is not possible in Java, since a method can not - and should not(!) - have any knowledge about the expressions used to calculate the values used for arguments. What if someone would write:

```
putData("ROBBY")
```

There is no variable name - what should `putData` print?

If Java had a map literal, you could have something like:

```
putData({name:"ROBBY"})
```

and `putData` would know that `name` is the key and "ROBBY" is the value and know how to print it. Still not what you wanted - but close.

Anyways, I also dislike string concatenation, and prefer to use `printf`:

```
System.out.printf("name = %s\n",name);
```

You still need to write `name` twice(can't go around that), but it's less ugly.

Comment: Please refer to Accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

I'm answering my own first question of many months ago.

The PL/I "put data" statement can be faked by the Netbeans code template `soutv`:

```
System.out.println("${EXP instanceof="<any>" default="exp"} = " + ${EXP});
```

Typing `soutv` (and then hitting tab) gives the following template:

[image]

Since the first occurrence of `args` is "boxed" in "refactor format", it's semi-obvious that, whatever it is changed to, the other `args` changes similarly. So if I type `now` in the "args box" (and then hit enter), the statement becomes:

```
   System.out.println("now = " + now);
```

It's good enough. Only thing I don't get is the PL/I nicety of being able to say

`put data(a,b,c)`

and getting

`a = ..., b = ..., c = ...`.

But I'm sort of happy with the development. Hope it helps others.